Git LFS hint: Your push was rejected due to missing or corrupt local objects
hint: Your push was rejected due to missing or corrupt local objects.
I installed lfs, git lfs migrate import --include="directory name/**", git add, commit, but when I try to push I get this error. Any idea what might be going on? Thanks in advance.
